# PHP - Escaping em dashes

Tags: php, forms, encoding

I am $_POST'ing the following headline from a form:

```
Google’s New Partner Android Update Initiative: Very Promising — Maybe; We’ll See
```

And on the handler page, if the first thing I do is

```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  die();
```

I see:

```
Googleâ€™s New Partner Android Update Initiative: Very Promising â€” Maybe; Weâ€™ll See
```

I understand that there are functions to convert & escape characters and their HTML equivalents, but how can I ensure that this content is added into the $_POST in the correct encoding?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if that helps, but it seems like the UTF-8 encoding got mixed up (control characters seem somewhat familiar to me ...). Try to output with [utf8_encode()](http://www.php.net/utf8_encode) or [utf8_decode()](http://www.php.net/utf8_decode).

Comment: When I utf8_decode() what is posted I get "Google?s New Partner Android Update Initiative: Very Promising ? Maybe; We?ll See". I'm more asking why it gets put into the $_POST in that format to begin with. Thx.

Comment: what happens if you try to output with utf8_encode() ? I guess the problem is the form is submitted with the wrong charset/content-type. Try determining the charset which is used by your browser. Alternatively set via PHP `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` or HTML Meta Tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Outputting with utf8_encode() outputs the original string I've posted in the question. I already have a <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> tag on the form

Comment: Is there may be an http header set that takes precedence over the meta tag? Try to include the PHP `header()` directive I've posted in the comment before. Maybe that helps? You may also check [mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to see what encoding your output uses.

Comment: Adding header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); on the handler page and the <meta> tag on the form seemed to do the trick. I also ensured the database collation was on utf8_unicode_ci. When displaying the content back out, I also had some calls to htmlentities() and stripslashes() that was altering the characters. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. No problem, glad I could help. So just to sum it up: Adding the header() with the correct content-type did the trick? I guess then your webserver is sending a wrong content-type per default (e.g. ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 or something like that.) I guess you nay check that in the server config to avoid similiar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Both the page with the form, and the displaying page need to use the same charset.  To reproduce the behavior you show, I had to create 2 pages, one a form, with

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

which posted to a page without that.

If I put the meta tag in both pages, it outputs correctly, if I remove it from both pages, it outputs correctly.

If only the form has it, you get what you posted, and if only the receiving page has it, you get the ?'s.

---

test.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<form method="post" action="test2.php">
<input type="text" name="string">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

test2.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['string']))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['string']);
    die();
}
?>
```

If I paste your string into the input box in test.php, hit submit, I get it back properly in test2.php.  If I remove the first line of test2.php, I get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Both my form page and displaying page have that tag in it and I still see what is posted. The tag is in the header code of my site, consistent across all pages

Comment: I'll update my answer with the example I used.  See if the problem happens in your browser/server combination with my example, and if not maybe something else in your page is effecting it.

Comment: See my comment above for what did the trick. Thanks for your help John.